# Piping the output of an interactive shell script

Tags: shell, pipe, pacman, interactive

Arch Linux's package manager, [`pacman`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman), outputs search results with each result spanning two lines:

```bsh
~ % pacman -Ss cowsay
extra/cowsay 3.04-2
    Configurable talking cow (and a few other creatures)
community/ponysay 3.0.3-4
    cowsay reimplemention for ponies
```

There are ways to grep this output (`grep -C 1`, etc), but I prefer to wrap the call and pipe the output through `paste - - | column -s $'\t' -t`. This leaves each search result on its own line:

```bsh
~ % pacman -Ss cowsay
community/ponysay 3.0.3-4 (1.3 MiB 10.7 MiB)    cowsay reimplemention for ponies
extra/cowsay 3.04-2 (19.5 KiB 38.2 KiB)         Configurable talking cow (and a few other creatures)
```

So far so good. But I also use a tool called [`yay`](https://github.com/Jguer/yay), which essentially a wrapper around `pacman`, with added functionality for managing packages in the [Arch User Repository](https://aur.archlinux.org/) (AUR). `yay` includes an interactive search/install command that is triggered by just passing a search term with no other options:

```bsh
~ % yay cowsay
15 aur/ponysay-free 3.0.2-1 (+1 0.00)
    Awesome cowsay reimplemention with ponies for ponies. Only free ponies edition
[...]
4 aur/xcowsay 1.5.1-1 (+17 0.38)
    a program based on cowsay that displays a cute cow and message on your desktop
3 aur/muccadoro 1.0.1-1 (+1 0.79)
    Pomodoro timer using figlet, cowsay, and optionally lolcat
2 community/ponysay 3.0.3-4 (1.3 MiB 10.7 MiB)
    cowsay reimplemention for ponies
1 extra/cowsay 3.04-2 (19.5 KiB 38.2 KiB)
    Configurable talking cow (and a few other creatures)
==> Packages to install (eg: 1 2 3, 1-3 or ^4)
==> 1
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (1)   New Version  Net Change  Download Size

extra/cowsay  3.04-2         0.04 MiB       0.02 MiB

Total Download Size:   0.02 MiB
Total Installed Size:  0.04 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages...
cowsay-3.04-2-any                                                 19.5 KiB  49.5 KiB/s 00:00 [#######################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                [#######################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                              
[...]
```

For the sake of uniformity, I was hoping to apply my search result fix to this function as well, but the interactivity, and the fact that there are lines with no line breaks (`==>` ), it is requiring some different approaches.

I need to alter just the search results part, and then pass through the rest of the script directly.

I wrote a little perl script that's sort of like my `paste`/`column`, but with a kill switch:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$thru = 0;
while (<>) {
    if ( $thru == 1 || m/Packages to install / ) {
        $thru = 1;
    } else {
        chomp unless (m/^ /);
        s/^\s+/\t/;
    }
    print;
}
```

But when I pipe the output through that, I lose progress bars and the text before prompts.

Here's a diff:

```
--- correctnot.txt      2021-10-29 15:09:43.645632751 -0500
+++ correct.txt 2021-10-29 15:09:43.655632810 -0500
@@ -1,22 +1,22 @@
==> Packages to install (eg: 1 2 3, 1-3 or ^4)
-1
-==> resolving dependencies...
+==> 1
+resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
-:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
+
Package (1)   New Version  Net Change

extra/cowsay  3.04-2         0.04 MiB

Total Installed Size:  0.04 MiB

-Y
-checking keyring...
-checking package integrity...
-loading package files...
-checking for file conflicts...
-checking available disk space...
+:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
+(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                [#######################################################] 100%
+(1/1) checking package integrity                                                              [#######################################################] 100%
+(1/1) loading package files                                                                   [#######################################################] 100%
+(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                             [#######################################################] 100%
+(1/1) checking available disk space                                                           [#######################################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
-installing cowsay...
+(1/1) installing cowsay                                                                       [#######################################################] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/3) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
(2/3) Refreshing PackageKit...
```

In another attempt, I recreated everything before the first prompt, then passed the answer to a second call:

```bsh
echo q |
    /usr/bin/yay "$@" |
    perl -pe 'if ( m/Packages to install / ) { print; s/Packages to install.*//; chomp; print; exit; } chomp unless (m/^ /); s/^\s+/\t/'
read answer
echo "$answer" | exec /usr/bin/yay "$@"
```

The output:

```bsh
15 aur/ponysay-free 3.0.2-1 (+1 0.00)   Awesome cowsay reimplemention with ponies for ponies. Only free ponies edition
[...]
4 aur/xcowsay 1.5.1-1 (+17 0.38)        a program based on cowsay that displays a cute cow and message on your desktop
3 aur/muccadoro 1.0.1-1 (+1 0.79)       Pomodoro timer using figlet, cowsay, and optionally lolcat
2 community/ponysay 3.0.3-4 (1.3 MiB 10.7 MiB)  cowsay reimplemention for ponies
1 extra/cowsay 3.04-2 (19.5 KiB 38.2 KiB)       Configurable talking cow (and a few other creatures)
==> Packages to install (eg: 1 2 3, 1-3 or ^4)
==> 1
15 aur/ponysay-free 3.0.2-1 (+1 0.00)
    Awesome cowsay reimplemention with ponies for ponies. Only free ponies edition
[...]
4 aur/xcowsay 1.5.1-1 (+17 0.38)
    a program based on cowsay that displays a cute cow and message on your desktop
3 aur/muccadoro 1.0.1-1 (+1 0.79)
    Pomodoro timer using figlet, cowsay, and optionally lolcat
2 community/ponysay 3.0.3-4 (1.3 MiB 10.7 MiB)
    cowsay reimplemention for ponies
1 extra/cowsay 3.04-2 (19.5 KiB 38.2 KiB)
    Configurable talking cow (and a few other creatures)
==> Packages to install (eg: 1 2 3, 1-3 or ^4)
==> resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (1)   New Version  Net Change

extra/cowsay  3.04-2         0.04 MiB

Total Installed Size:  0.04 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]  -> exit status 1
```

Starts off well, but it output the results twice, and I had to run the command twice. No go.

*Side note: I should probably mention, the return on investment is very low here. Why would I want to grep an interactive list anyway? At this point, I might as well just fork `yay` and delete the `\n` from my copy ([i did](https://github.com/Jguer/yay/pull/1625). But I'm still curious, is there a straightforward way to alter the output of an interactive program like this?*

Comment: Can you get the result you want by lying to the program? `env COLUMNS=511 yay cowsay`?

Comment: Good idea @waltinator but it's hardcoded: https://github.com/Jguer/yay/blob/next/pkg/query/types.go#L133